# New document version and old document version

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a form that I had to create a new version of. I don't want anyone to be able to use the old form, but we need to be able to access, modify the entries in the old version of the document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

As long as you are only modifying the entries of the old form on the Entries page you can set up the [Limited Availability](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/17/building-forms/form-settings#form-availability) feature on the Build page. By setting an end date you can then show an unavailable message for the form, that will prevent your end users form filling it out.